# how to communicate thermostat to turn on wood heat system when during heat pump defrost cycle

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I have physically disconnected the strip heaters in my air handler but the fan still runs which I do not want.  I have a wood boiler I want to run in place of the aux heat

1. Can I disconnect the white wire from the thermostat and use this to signal a relay to turn on wood heat blower ?
2. Will the system still defrost if the white wire is disconnected at the thermostat?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This sounds pretty complex; would you be able to add some more information, or even a diagram? That way we'd be much more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: How is the wood boiler currently controlled?  Also, is the thermostat controlling defrost, or is there a separate defrost control in the heat pump?

Comment: I have 2 TS now that separately control HP and wood boiler (WB). The defrost cycle of the HP is typical meaning no separate control. If the w wire comes from the outside unit to the TS inside then could that be used to initiate a sequence to activate the WB?  The WB boiler is wired via Delta T with hi lo limits etc that enegergizes pumps ,blowers etc which is ultimately controlled by inside TS

Comment: the show stopper to my plan is that - does the air handler inside have to run during the defrost cycle ?   Thanks for your responses

Comment: Hello three Phase- your name begs another question please.  I am building a rotor phase using a 10 hp motor and start and run capacitors. How do you determine proper sized start and run capacitors and can bleed resistors be used to take the start cap out of circuit once slave motor is running.   Thank for any direction